# CLIENT wrappermode (port smtps/465) is unimplemented

Tags: centos, email, postfix

I am getting the following error when I try to send email using a relayhost from a CentOS 7 server using postfix:

```
Oct 19 19:53:08 localhost postfix/pickup[7174]: 64DAF1A53CB: uid=1002 from=<me>
Oct 19 19:53:08 localhost postfix/cleanup[7184]: 64DAF1A53CB: message-id=<20151020025308.64DAF1A53CB@mydomain.com>
Oct 19 19:53:08 localhost postfix/qmgr[7175]: 64DAF1A53CB: from=<me@mydomain.com>, size=447, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 19 19:53:08 localhost postfix/smtp[7177]: CLIENT wrappermode (port smtps/465) is unimplemented
Oct 19 19:53:08 localhost postfix/smtp[7177]: instead, send to (port submission/587) with STARTTLS
Oct 19 19:53:18 localhost postfix/smtp[7177]: 64DAF1A53CB: to=<test.account@anotherdomain.com>, relay=emailserver.com[ip.of.email.server]:465, delay=10, delays=0.06/0/10/0, dsn=d.s.n, status=deferred (lost connection with emailserver.com[ip.of.email.server] while receiving the initial server greeting)
```

The steps I took leading up to this are:

```
# yum -y install postfix cyrus-sasl-plain mailx
# systemctl restart postfix
# systemctl enable postfix
# vi /etc/postfix/main.cf
//Add the following at THE VERY END OF THE FILE:
myhostname = mydomain.com
relayhost = [emailserver.com]:465
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
// save and close, then create the following new file:
# vi /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
// add the following one line:
[emailserver.com]:465 username:password
// save and close the file
// create a postfix lookup table by running the following command:
# postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
// restrict access to the file:
# chown root:postfix /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd*
# chmod 640 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd*
# systemctl reload postfix
```

Then I set up a new user on CentOS named "me" and entered the following command:

```
echo "This is a test." | mail -s "test message" test.account@anotherdomain.com
```

**When I change `port 465` to `port 587` in the above commands, I am able to successfully send a message using the `echo` command.  However, the emailserver.com customer support line says that `port 465` is `SSL only`, and that `port 587` has `SSL disabled`, so the problem here is that SSL does not work.  How can I set this up so that `SSL SMTP` is sent through `port 465`?**

Note that the CentOS 7 development server is behind a residential cable modem with `port 25` disabled, so I have no choice but to use a relayhost.  Also, I want to use `port 465` to ensure an SSL connection.  The email must travel via SSL.

The entire `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file contents are:

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES

#####################################################################
### Everything below was added to set up relayhost for smtp
#####################################################################

myhostname = mydomain.com

relayhost = [emailserver.com]:465
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
```

NOTE: In firewalld, I set the smtp.xml file to use `port 465` for smtp instead of `port 25`.  But I did not create an `smtps` service.  I don't think this is relevant, but I thought I would share it in case it is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this posting, the server on which I was testing the above did not have its own signed SSL certificate.  (It was using a private certificate at that time.)  The remote mail server required a signed SSL certificate and thus refused the OP's request for connections, and thus triggered the error which led to this posting.

In this case, the resolution involved using a signed SSL certificate.  But the error could also be resolved by using mail servers that allow trusted unsigned certificates, or by sending unencrypted requests.

Comment: Use TLS, 587 (emailserver.com:submission) and not 465.  TLS1.2 is far more secure & compatible than SSL wrappers and wouldn't have this issue..